# How to close port 80 in Salesforce?

Tags: login, custom-domain, mydomain, network

During our security scan we noticed that port 80 was opened. There is a redirect to https, but we would like to know if we can close port 80 altogether. Perhaps by making use of a custom domain?

Here are the results from the port scan:
[image]

Comment: You can try a [non-Salesforce CDN to serve your custom domain](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_mgmt_domain_config_options.htm&type=5). Your CDN _might_ be able to block port 80. It's worth noting that closing 80 [will not improve your security](https://scotthelme.co.uk/why-closing-port-80-is-bad-for-security/), therefore this question is an example of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)